# Python package to calculate static force and moments of rigid body

Tags: python, software-recommendation

Which Python package is suited for solving problems of the following type?

Given the rigid body depicted in violet in the following sketch

[image: Example: Three coordinate systems, force and moments]

I would like to do the following:

- Define cartesian coordinate systems $\text{cs0}(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, $\text{cs1}(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $\text{cs2}(x_2, y_2, z_2)$.
- Specify forces and moments acting on the center of coordinate systems.
- Calculate forces and moments acting on fixed clamp at origin of $\text{cs0}$.

In order to preserve flexibility and intuitive usage, object orientated syntax would be preferred.
Pseudocode:

```
...
cs0 = initCartesianCoordinatesystem()
cs1 = cartesianCoordinatesystem( cs0, tranlationX = 0, translationY = 20,\
    translationZ = 0, rotationX = 0, rotationY = 0, rotationZ = 0)
cs2 = cartesianCoordinatesystem( cs1, translationX = 10, translationY = 0,\
    translationZ = 0, rotationX = 0, rotationY = 135, rotationZ = 0)

body = rigidBody()
body.addForce( cs1, (1, 0, 0) )
body.addMoment( cs1, (0, 0, 1) )
body.addMoment( cs2, (0, 2, 0) )
force, moment = body.staticEquilibrium( cs0 )
```

Leading to 
$$ force = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}_{\text{cs0}} $$
$$ moment = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2+20 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}_{\text{cs0}} $$

The following features would be helpful:

- Visualization
- Units

Comment: I think that you could use [SymPy Mechanics](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/mechanics/index.html).